# Removing XPM temporary files after exceptions

Tags: experience-manager, infrastructure

I'm currently working on a system which has some problems, and we're seeing exceptions during the update preview. Apart from the problem of the exceptions themselves, which of course, we are trying to solve, we have noticed that the temporary versions of things like javascript files are not getting cleaned up.

This makes sense, I suppose. If an exception occurs, the rest of the action won't be processed, including any clean-up. Or should I expect experience manager to clean up properly after itself regardless?

In the normal running of a system, now and then you will get exceptions. I can imagine we could write a script that would delete any file with a guid in it's name, but that might have it's own issues. Is there perhaps a way to trigger Tridion/XPM to do a clean-up of files that it's otherwise "forgotten"? What other strategies might we follow?