# How can I purge old session preview data?

Tags: content-delivery, experience-manager, session-preview

I need to take a filesystem backup of a website with Experience Manager enabled and I want to exclude all of the session preview pages and binaries:

> index_d6550f29-5662-451d-bc90-a7dd9e83e6e9.html

It seems that a number of these have been left over either due to sessions that have remained open or failures during prior cleanup operations.

Is there a way of forcing a purge of existing/leftover session preview content delivery files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of my question from earlier today. (spooky) http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/13276/129

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should happen automatically if the staging site's app pool identity is setup correctly. In IIS you need to set the app pool identity to NETWORK SERVICE, and then give NETWORK SERVICE file system permissions to write and delete.

Assumes a dotnet implementation of XM but same concept applies for a jsp/Tomcat setup.

Comment: Can confirm that the leftover files were due to a permissions issue but it looks like the only way of getting rid of all of the old session data is to delete the lot and republish the whole site!